# For loop on two arrays of points

Tags: python, arrays, performance, for-loop, euclidean-distance

I have two arrays of points: **list1** with **list1.shape = [N, 3]** and **list2** with **list2.shape = [M, 3]**. Within **N, M**: the total number of point, *(x, y, z)* are 3 coordinates in 3D.

Now I want to check if each point of **list1** is within a distance **r** with each point of **list2**. A nature way to do this is a for loop:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        if (list1[i, 0] - list2[j, 0])**2 + (list1[i, 1] - list2[j, 1])**2 + (list1[i, 2] - list2[j, 2])**2 < r**2:
        ''' Return 1 if list1[i] is within list2[j] '''
            return True
        else:
        ''' Return 0 if list1[i] is not within list2[j] '''
            return False
```

But it's horribly slow. Could I do the more efficient way?

Comment: May be k-d tree is the solution? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: I tried with KdTree of scipy but it's not faster.

Comment: The nicest solution for a euclidean distance matrix is in this **question** :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518574/why-does-looping-beat-indexing-here  . Replace one 'Data' with list1 and the other with list2

Comment: Your code would overwrite `a[i]` multiple times, and only the value `j==M-1` would matter. How do you actually need it to behave?

Comment: Sorry for the mistaken, I modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the outer operations to calculate the distance matrix without the for loops:

```
s = np.subtract.outer

d_matrix = s(list1[:,0], list2[:,0])**2
d_matrix += s(list1[:,1], list2[:,1])**2
d_matrix += s(list1[:,2], list2[:,2])**2
```

Where each line is the distance of point i about all points. To find out if point i is close to any point using your criterion:

```
a = np.zeros_like(list1[:,0])
a[np.any(d_matrix < r**2, axis=1)] = 1
```

Comment: @user2863620 but you should give a try in K-d Tree, since it calculates only the upper triangle of the `d_matrix` and therefore is more efficient (if you need)

Comment: With M, N is small. Kd-Tree seems not be faster than the brute force way.